# Accessing data in a spreadsheet through VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable, spreadsheet

So I'm a little rusty on my VB.NET skills, but I decided to take up a project to get me working in it again. Problem is I've hit a slight road block and I was hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.

I have a spreadsheet (or 3, but they could be combined if that makes it easier) that contain interest rates. I need my program to use user-input to select which interest rate it needs and then calculate and output the grand total, without the end user ever seeing or even being aware of the interest rate table.

So far all my google-fu is turning up is how to create a spreadsheet using VB.NET which is kinda the opposite of my intention. Anybody got any ideas I could try? These tables are not especially long, so I can import and read them or if need be re-enter them somewhere in the .NET framework and package it with the program, I think the latter might actually be preferable for speed purposes. Any ideas?

Comment: Look for Visual Studio Tools for Office http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386107.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend packaging the spreadsheets with the program, say in a CSV, XML, or JSON format that can be easily read with a library.

For the initial import, though, I would recommend COM interop with Excel through the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  One articles on this topic (for C# rather than VB, unfortunately) is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084).